# Convert URL with query parameters to guzzle

Tags: php, url, request, guzzle

Using "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3", how can I convert a URL including query parameters to a syntax where an options array is used?

```
$exampleUrl = http://A001234/datadownload/test?reference=abc&opt_responseformat=json&opt_servicemode=async
```

Pasting this in browser or POSTMAN gives me a nice little JSON stump back. But I have not been able to use this with an options array. Here is some code, that I tried:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([        
    'headers' => [            
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 
    ],
    'verify' => false
]);

$result = $client->request('GET', 'http://A001234/datadownload/test', [
    "form_params" => [
        "opt_responseformat" => "json",
        "opt_servicemode"=> "async"
    ]
]);
if($result->getStatusCode() == 200) {
    dd(json_decode($result->getBody())); // dumps null expecting json object
}
```

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([        
    'headers' => [            
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json' 
    ],
    'verify' => false
]);

$result = $client->request('GET', 'http://A001234/datadownload/test', [
    "query" => [
        "reference" => "abc",
        "opt_responseformat" => "json",
        "opt_servicemode"=> "async"
    ]
]);
if($result->getStatusCode() == 200) {
    dd(json_decode($result->getBody())); // dumps null expecting json object
}
```